# Tkinter auto scrolling frame almost working. Apreciate input

Tags: scroll, tkinter, scrollbar, frame, autoscroll

I am trying to develop a scrollable frame in tkinter that can be used in the same way a normal frame can.
Thanks to many hint in this forum i develloped some code, that does exactly what it is supposed to, if i pack the scrollframe in the root window.

Unfortunately it fails if i use place or grid.

Here the code for the Frame

```
    import tkinter as tk

    class ScrollFrame(tk.Frame):  #this frame will be placed on a canvas that is in a frame that goes on the parent window
        class AutoScrollbar(tk.Scrollbar):
            def set(self, *args):
                if float(args[0])==0 and float(args[1])==1: self.grid_forget()
                else:
                    if self.cget('orient')=="vertical": self.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="ns")
                    else: self.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky="ew")
                tk.Scrollbar.set(self, *args)

        def __init__(self, root,*args,**args2):
            self.outer_frame=tk.Frame(root,*args,**args2)   #this is the frame that will be packed in th parent window
            self.outer_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
            self.outer_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=2)
            self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.outer_frame, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, self.canvas,*args,**args2)
            self.vscroll = ScrollFrame.AutoScrollbar(self.outer_frame, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
            self.hscroll = ScrollFrame.AutoScrollbar(self.outer_frame, orient="horizontal",  command=self.canvas.xview)
            self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vscroll.set, xscrollcommand=self.hscroll.set)

            self.canvas.create_window((0,0), window=self, anchor="nw")
            self.canvas.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="news")
            self.hscroll.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky="ew")
            self.vscroll.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="ns")

            self.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)

        def onFrameConfigure(self, event): #Adapt the scroll region   #does the resizing
            self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))
            self.canvas.config(width=event.width, height=event.height)

        #convenience functions so the ScrollFrame can be treated like a normal frame

        def destr_org(self):tk.Frame.destroy(self)
        def destroy(self):
            self.destroy=self.destr_org
            self.outer_frame.destroy()
        def pack(self,*args,**arg2):
            self.outer_frame.pack(*args,**arg2)
        def place(self,*args,**arg2):
            self.outer_frame.place(*args,**arg2)
        def grid(self,*args,**arg2):
            self.outer_frame.grid(*args,**arg2)
        def pack_forget(self,*args,**arg2):
            self.outer_frame.pack_forget(*args,**arg2)
        def place_forget(self,*args,**arg2):
            self.outer_frame.place_forget(*args,**arg2)
        def grid_forget(self,*args,**arg2):
            self.outer_frame.grid_forget(*args,**arg2)
        def config(self,*args,**arg2):
            self.outer_frame.config(*args,**arg2)
            tk.Frame.config(self,*args,**arg2)
        def configure(self,*args,**arg2):
            self.outer_frame.config(*args,**arg2)
            tk.Frame.config(self,*args,**arg2)
```

here the code i used to test it. Just uncomment the f.place and f.grid lines to try them.

```
    win=tk.Tk()
    f=ScrollFrame(win)

    for n in range(10):
        o=tk.Button(f,text="-----------------------"+str(n)+"------------------------")
        o.pack()

    f.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
    #f.place(x=0, y=0)
    #f.grid(column=0,row=0)
```

Since i get no errors i am somewat lost and would be grateful for hints why it doesnt work. 
I know there are packages with scrollable frames, but i really would like to get a frame without additional imports.
Its also tru that it is a little more complicated than necessary, but that is because I tried to design it in a way that it can be filled and placed exactly like a tk.Frame

Thanks a lot

Comment: You never layout the cons_frame. Add `self.termf.pack()`.

Comment: I made this as well once. Here's my version: https://gist.github.com/novel-yet-trivial/3eddfce704db3082e38c84664fc1fdf8

Comment: Oh, thanks. Corrected the laying out. Now the Button shows, but the scrolling isn't any better. Weird, that the buttons showed anyways even though the cons_frame wasnt packed/displayed??

Comment: So, i made a quick test with your code. Works pretty well, but seems to have problems with place as well.

Comment: Ok, the problem with the termf was my fault. It works as expected so I deleted it from the Question. The Problem with  `ScrollFrame.place` still remains.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.
This works quite well for pack() and place() (didnt try to get grid working) (on Linux)
The key for place() is the binding to the resizing of the parent window, whereas for pack() the resizing of the inner frame (=self) seems to be important.

Even though the code of Novel (see comments above) is quite more elegant than mine, it sometimes gave me errors were this one worked :-)

```
            class ScrollFrame(tk.Frame):
                class AutoScrollbar(tk.Scrollbar):
                    def set(self, *args):
                        if float(args[0])==0 and float(args[1])==1: self.grid_forget()
                        else:
                            if self.cget('orient')=="vertical": self.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="ns")
                            else: self.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky="ew")
                        tk.Scrollbar.set(self, *args)

                def __init__(self, root,*args,**args2):
                    self.rootwin=root
                    self.dir=tk.BOTH
                    if "dir" in args2:
                        self.dir=args2["dir"]
                        del(args2["dir"])
                    self.outer_frame=tk.Frame(root,*args,**args2)
                    self.outer_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
                    self.outer_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=2)
                    self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.outer_frame, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
                    tk.Frame.__init__(self, self.canvas,*args,**args2)
                    if self.dir==tk.Y or self.dir==tk.BOTH :
                        self.vscroll = ScrollFrame.AutoScrollbar(self.outer_frame, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
                        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vscroll.set)
                        self.vscroll.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="ns")
                    if self.dir==tk.X or self.dir==tk.BOTH :
                        self.hscroll = ScrollFrame.AutoScrollbar(self.outer_frame, orient="horizontal",  command=self.canvas.xview)
                        self.canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=self.hscroll.set)
                        self.hscroll.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky="ew")
                    self.canvas.create_window((0,0), window=self, anchor="nw")
                    self.canvas.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="news")

                    self.canvas.bind("<Enter>", self._bind_mouse)
                    self.canvas.bind("<Leave>", self._unbind_mouse)

                def onFrameConfigure(self, event): #Adapt the scroll region
                    bb=self.canvas.bbox("all")
                    self.canvas.config(scrollregion=bb)
                    self.canvas.config(height=event.height,width=event.width)
                def onRootConf(self, event):
                    bb=self.canvas.bbox("all")
                    self.canvas.config(scrollregion=bb)
                    w=bb[2]-bb[0]
                    h=bb[3]-bb[1]
                    rw=self.rootwin.winfo_width()-self.outer_frame.winfo_x()-20*int(self.vscroll.winfo_ismapped())
                    rh=self.rootwin.winfo_height()-self.outer_frame.winfo_y()-20*int(self.hscroll.winfo_ismapped())
                    if rh<h and (self.dir==tk.Y or self.dir==tk.BOTH):
                        h=rh
                    if rw<w and (self.dir==tk.X or self.dir==tk.BOTH):
                        w=rw
                    self.canvas.config(height=h,width=w)

                def destr_org(self):tk.Frame.destroy(self)
                def destroy(self):
                    self.destroy=self.destr_org
                    self.outer_frame.destroy()
                def pack(self,*args,**arg2):
                    self.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)
                    self.outer_frame.pack(*args,**arg2)
                def place(self,*args,**arg2):
                    self.outer_frame.place(*args,**arg2)
                    self.bind("<Configure>",self.onRootConf)
                    self.rootwin.bind("<Configure>",self.onRootConf)
                def grid(self,*args,**arg2):
                    self.outer_frame.grid(*args,**arg2)
                def pack_forget(self,*args,**arg2):
                    self.outer_frame.pack_forget(*args,**arg2)
                def place_forget(self,*args,**arg2):
                    self.outer_frame.place_forget(*args,**arg2)
                def grid_forget(self,*args,**arg2):
                    self.outer_frame.grid_forget(*args,**arg2)
                def config(self,*args,**arg2):
                    self.outer_frame.config(*args,**arg2)
                    tk.Frame.config(self,*args,**arg2)
                def configure(self,*args,**arg2):
                    self.outer_frame.config(*args,**arg2)
                    tk.Frame.config(self,*args,**arg2)
                def winfo_ismapped(self):
                    return self.outer_frame.winfo_ismapped()

                def _bind_mouse(self, event=None):
                    self.canvas.bind_all("<4>", self._on_mousewheel)
                    self.canvas.bind_all("<5>", self._on_mousewheel)
                    self.canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self._on_mousewheel)
                def _unbind_mouse(self, event=None):
                    self.canvas.unbind_all("<4>")
                    self.canvas.unbind_all("<5>")
                    self.canvas.unbind_all("<MouseWheel>")
                def _on_mousewheel(self, event):    
                    if event.num == 4 or event.delta == 120: self.canvas.yview_scroll(-1, "units" )
                    elif event.num == 5 or event.delta == -120: self.canvas.yview_scroll(1, "units" )
```